# How do I sign an XLA (Excel add in)?

Tags: vba, code-signing, xla

And is is possible to do that from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible probably, but not by any prebuilt API that I know of. If you could sign code from code it would allow self modifying to stay signed. That would be a bit of a security issue.

Now VBA does allow for binary read/writes you could slap a monitor on your application and watch what happens when you sign code and replicate what it is doing. But I'd guess that would be pretty non-trivial.

You could of course kludge together using sendkeys... But don't.

Out of curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If the XLA is not signed you get a warning (or even a failure depending on some policy) when you start Excel with the add-in.  We have a code signing certificate, but it is only available to the buildmaster on the build machine so I was wondering how to make a script that would sign the XLA on our build machine.

Comment: Honestly, it's probably more trouble than it's worth. Any solution you came up with would be so much worse than just doing it manually. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.