# How do I sign an Excel XLA

Tags: excel, vba, code-signing

I am trying to sign an XLA file of our with our code signing certificate. I am following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/digital-signatures-code-signing) but they require that Excel know of the signing certificate.

Is this a workable way to do this? And if so, what else do I need to do?

Or is there a way to do it with signtool (it tells me it's an invalid file format)?

Or some other way?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652100/how-do-i-sign-an-xla-from-excel-2016-with-a-timestamp) (never says how to do it) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234457/how-do-i-sign-an-xla-excel-add-in) (asks how to do so in code - and the reply is you can't) don't answer this.

Comment: Asking for best ways to do something is opinion based.

Comment: @Luuklag At present I'll take any way to do this. But I'll remove the word "best" even though 90% of the answers here are fundamentally an individual's opinion of the best way to do something. I for one never provide a 2nd best way to solve a problem.